# Rails3: Is there a server-side analytics?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a server-side analytics for Rails?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Newrelic: http://newrelic.com/

Answer (score 1):

[NewRelic](http://newrelic.com) - real-time monitoring of Rails, DB, Memcache, Background taks

[Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) / [Nagious](http://www.nagios.org/) - monitoring CPU, LA, RAM, IO, NET over SNMP

**updated**
I'd like to suggest you the [video discussion](http://webpulp.tv/post/573991716/37signals-mark-imbriaco) by Mark Imbriaco (37signals admin)

Answer (score 0):

There was one a year ago called [Weed-3](https://github.com/courtenay/weed-3) but I do not believe there is any that work with Rails 3 currently.